# How to display numeric columns in an R dataframe without scientific notation ('e+07')

Tags: r, types, dataframe

I have an R dataframe with one column containing a stringt of numbers but I would like to treat them as a factor (mainly to stop R shortening the numbers using e+04 etc...).  One way I have found to fix this problem is to edit the csv file the data is taken from, and add a dummy entry that has a word in the desired column and then reimporting it.  How do I get this effect using R functions without messing around with the csv?

To clarify, my dataframe looks like this:

```
pNum,Condition,numberEntered
1,2,5.0970304e+07
```

I want to change the data type of numberEntered from numeric to factor and get rid of the pesky e+07.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As Joshua said, it is a printing issue not a storage issue.  You can change the way all numbers are printed (=by adjusting `getOption("scipen")`.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 509703045845, 0.0001)
print(x)
options(scipen = 50)
print(x)
```

Alternatively, you may wish to change the way just those numbers are formatted.  (This converts them to `character`.) It is worth getting to know `format` and `formatC`.  To get you started, compare

```
format(x)
format(x, digits = 10)
format(x, digits = 3)
format(x, digits = 3, scientific = 5)
format(x, trim = TRUE, digits = 3, scientific = 5)
formatC(x)
formatC(x, format = "fg")
formatC(x, format = "fg", flag = "+")
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was very informative indeed and fixed my issue.  Thanks for providing me with the useful examples.

Comment: To add a point of clarification, `format` and `formatC` don't change the way the numbers are printed; they convert the numbers to character using the specified format.

Comment: Is it possible to change a numeric vector to scientific notation without converting it to a character?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to say, but you've been spending time trying to fix a problem that doesn't exist.  Use `str` to check the types of data in your data.frame and you'll see that `numberEntered` is `num` and it isn't being "shortened".  The only issue is the number of significant digits being *printed*.

```
options(digits=7)
(x <- data.frame(pNum=1,Condition=2,numberEntered=509703045845))
options(digits=10)
x
```

You can use `options(digits=22)` to set it to print the maximum number of significant digits.  See `?options` for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've played around with the digits option a bit but I suspect I don't understand it.  The numbers will vary in length between 2 and 8 in that column so I am not sure what to set the digits value to.  I  need it to show 2.139 instead of 2.1390000e+00 and 3924.75 instead of 3.9247500e+03 (this is what is displayed after using options(digits=8)

Comment: That looks like it might be an issue with `options(scipen)`.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise against storing floating-point numbers as factors... but you can still do it. But I have also included several other options.

```
> txt <- "pNum,Condition,numberEntered
+ 1,2,5.0970304e+07"
> dat <- read.csv(textConnection(txt),colClasses=c("integer","integer","factor"))
> dat
  pNum Condition numberEntered
1    1         2 5.0970304e+07
> dat[,3]
[1] 5.0970304e+07
Levels: 5.0970304e+07
> dat <- read.csv(textConnection(txt),colClasses=c("integer","integer","character"))
> dat[,3]
[1] "5.0970304e+07"
> dat <- read.csv(textConnection(txt),colClasses=c("integer","integer","numeric"))
> dat[,3]
[1] 50970304
> print.numeric <- function(...) formatC(...,format="f")
> print(dat[,3])
[1] "50970304.0000"
```