# Long number field does not retail string of digits due to Excel. Excel Office Professional 2013 converts digits to rounded number

Tags: r, numeric, exponential, r-factor

I'm reading a csv file in R that includes a conversion ID column.  The issue I'm running into is that my conversionID is being rounded as an exponential number.  Below is snapshot of the CSV file (opened in Excel) that I'm reading into R.  As you can see, the conversion ID is an exponential format, but the value is: 383305820480.

[image]

When I read the data into R, using the following lines, I got the following output.  Which looks like it's rounding the string of conversion IDs.

```
x<-read.csv("./Test2.csv")
options("scipen"=100, "digits"=15)
x
```

[image]

When I export the file as CSV, using the code

```
write.csv(x,"./Test3.csv")
```

I get the following output. As you can see, I no longer have a unique identifier as it rounds the number.

[image]

I also tried reading the file as a factor, using the code, but I get the same output with numbers rounded.  I need the Conversion.ID to be a unique identifier.

```
x<-read.csv("./Test2.csv", colClasses="character")
```

The only way I can get the Conversion ID column to stay as a unique identifier is to open the CSV file and write a ' in front of each conversion ID.  That is not scalable because I have hundreds of files.

Comment: how large is your data? can you specify the `colClasses` argument in `read.table` and set that as a character column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/force-r-not-to-use-exponential-notation-e-g-e10; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706677/how-to-display-numeric-columns-in-an-r-dataframe-without-scientific-notation-e/6707630#6707630 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356530/using-scientific-notation-in-r/16356730#16356730

Comment: @Henrik, that doesn't work.  It rounds the column, which I don't want.

Comment: @rawr, I tried reading it as a character column, but no luck.

Comment: @ekim: what does "no luck" mean? Can we have a reproducible example please?

Comment: @Ben, sorry no luck means it didn't work.

Comment: @ekim: "didn't work" is way too vague for us to help you. @rawr's suggestion is the standard way to do this.  To repeat, we will need more details (what code did you use? what are the results of applying `str()` to the results? what errors and/or warnings did you get?) Reproducible examples **strongly** preferred.

Comment: @Ben, thanks for the feedback.  I wrote some of my code and provided snapshots.  Hopefully that clarifies my problem.  Sorry for the vagueness, I've been staring at the screen all day.

Comment: @BenBolker: When I apply a str(), I get the following:    
'data.frame': 10 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Conversion.ID: num  3.83e+11 3.96e+13 2.14e+14 1.02e+15 1.22e+15 ...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback everyone.  I just figured out the issue.  It looks like Excel is converting the data, causing it to lose the digits.  If I avoid opening the file in Excel after downloading it, it retains all the digits.  I'm not sure if this is a known issue with newer version.  I'm using Excel Office Professional Plus 2013.

Comment: Wow. I knew there were issues ( http://dontuseexcel.wordpress.com/2013/02/07/dont-use-excel-for-biological-data/ , http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/gene-name-errors-and-excel-lessons-not-learned/ , http://datapub.cdlib.org/2014/04/10/abandon-all-hope-ye-who-enter-dates-in-excel/ , http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/tutorials/spreadsheet-addiction/ ) but this is a new one!

Comment: Thanks, @BenBolker for looking into this for me.  I was confused because I was troubleshooting/reproducing the problem using Excel OP 2013, which was the root of the problem.  Now I know.

Answer (score 2):

I can't replicate your experience.

(**Update**: OP reports that the problem is actually with Excel converting/rounding the data on import [!!!])

I created a file on disk with full precision (I don't know the least-significant digits of your data, you didn't show them except for the first element, but I put a non-zero value in the units place for illustration):

```
 writeLines(c(
 "Conversion ID",
 "    383305820480",
 "  39634500000002",
 " 213905000000002",
 "1016890000000002",
 "1220910000000002"),
 con="Test2.csv")
```

Read the file and print it with full precision (use `check.names=FALSE` for perfect "round trip" capability -- not something you want to do on a regular basis):

```
x <- read.csv("Test2.csv",check.names=FALSE)
options(scipen=100)
print(x,digits=20)
##      Conversion ID
## 1     383305820480
## 2   39634500000002
## 3  213905000000002
## 4 1016890000000002
## 5 1220910000000002
```

Looks OK.

Now write output (use `row.names=FALSE` to avoid adding row names/allow a clean round-trip):

```
write.csv(x,"Test3.csv",row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)
```

The least-mediated way to examine a file on disk from within R is `file.show()`:

```
file.show("Test3.csv")
## Conversion ID
## 383305820480
## 39634500000002
## 213905000000002
## 1016890000000002
## 1220910000000002

x3 <- read.csv("Test3.csv",check.names=FALSE)
all.equal(x,x3)  ## TRUE
```

Use system tools to check that the files are the same (except for white space differences -- the original file was right-justified):

```
system("diff -w Test2.csv Test3.csv")  ## no difference
```

If you have even longer ID strings you *will* need to read them as character to avoid loss of precision:

```
read.csv("Test2.csv",colClasses="character")
##      Conversion.ID
## 1     383305820480
## 2   39634500000002
## 3  213905000000002
## 4 1016890000000002
## 5 1220910000000002
```

You could probably round-trip through Excel more safely (if you still think that's a good idea) by importing as character and exporting *with quotation marks* to protect the values.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the issue. It looks like my version of Excel is converting the data, causing it to lose the digits. If I avoid opening the file in Excel after downloading it, it retains all the digits. I'm not sure if this is a known issue with newer version. I'm using Excel Office Professional Plus 2013.

Comment: Excel only saves the *displayed* precision to CSV. Simply let it show more didgits and you want lose precision.

Comment: @Roland The only way that worked is I placed an ' before the numbers in Excel.  However I had thousands of files to change, so it was not feasible.  You bring up a viable option, but I was thinking that it shouldn't require manual intervention.